# Moshe, Ramba"m and humility

Tags: rambam, moshe-rabbeinu, middos-character-traits, behaalotcha-parsha

Numbers 12:3 informs us that “the man Moses was very humble, more than any person on the face of the earth.”

[This article](http://booksnthoughts.com/behaalotcha-maimonides-vs-aristotle-on-the-golden-mean/) cites Rambam's (Maimonides) view that humility is an exception to Rambam's general agreement with the "Golden Mean" rule, namely that every person should always be exceedingly humble and one should possess no trace of pride or arrogance whatsoever.

My rav explained that in Moshe's case, his humility may have backfired. His reasoning:

It began when Eldad and Meidad prophesied in the camp. Yehoshua suggests to Moshe that these men be imprisoned, to which Moshe, in a display of humility says, "If only ALL of the nation were prophets."

His brother and sister speak *lashon hara* about Moshe, and Moshe does not respond. Perhaps, knowing that Moshe would not respond, because he was so humble, was an incentive for them to do this. Seeing a lack of response, perhaps, led to:

Korach and his men causing the uprising. Had Moses not been so humble and demonstrated a command of his leadership with Eldad and Meidad, instead, there's a chance that Korach's rising may not have occurred.

Did Ramba"m take note of any of the above situations regarding Moshe and either based on this analysis, or for any other reason state, somewhere else, that a leader of a nation or important group should on occasion NOT demonstrate humility?

**Note:** A possible answer could include any other source that analyzed the above situations with Moshe and disagreed with Rambam's principle.

**Note:** Answers should relate specifically to analyzing Moshe's behavior and not regarding a general rule of how others should behave in similar situations.

Comment: I know that about the King Shaul, his Anava was not right in one situation and because of this he was disqualified/

Comment: To Shaul Shmuel said אם קטן אתה בעיניך ראש בני ישראל אתה

Comment: Gemara in 6st chapter of Eruvin said that Yehoshua was more Halacha bifne Rabo and because of this he has no childs,

Comment: in light of the discussion on the question below, perhaps further clarify whether answers not involving Moshe are appropriate.

Comment: Another possible answer would be to take the pesukim and Rambam into account and disagree with your Rav's chiddush. One can easily guess the opposite and say the situations would have been worse had he not been such an anav.

Comment: @mevaqesh Sorry it took me a while to notice your comment. Inevitably, ideas that I had not thought of arise during comments and other discussions. I have placed an additional note in the question.

Comment: A possible answer may be the distinction between what is best for the individual (being completely humble) and what would have been best for the nation of Israel to have seen from Moshe at that time - standing up. This is not a contradiction, though - Moshe is punished for failing to sanctify Hashem's name (Lehakdisheini B'toch B'nei Yisroel) in a number of possible circumstances but Eldad/Meidad, Miriam/Aharon, and Adas Korach are not among them. Ergo, these are not failings of Moshe and his humility.

Comment: Moshe was a good prophet. Indeed he was a general in the Egyptian army. Though humble, I do not think we should attribute his misfortunes to his humility. G-d chose him because of his huge consideration for animals and yet the Rambam says we should act intelligently, not morally as the Garden of Eden story suggests. The golden mean are for those who cannot think, yet Moshe followed this rule and he indeed could think.

Answer (score 1):

end of [hilchot talmud torah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911561/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Seven.htm)

> When does the above apply? When [the person] spurned or embarrassed
>   [the torah sage] in private. However, if one spurns or embarrasses a
>   torah sage in public, it is forbidden for the sage to forgo his honor.
>   Indeed, if he does so, he is punished, because the disrespect of the
>   Torah is involved. Instead, he should seek vengeance and carry enmity
>   over the matter like a snake until the offender requests to be
>   pardoned. Then, he should forgive him.

btw, Moses' absolute humility was due to being so close to God. this is something that comes naturally to one who is in contact with God so closely.see [this](http://dafyomireview.com/audio/cord1.mp3). when man is in such close contact with God he realizes just how small he really is.

Comment: Did rambam take note of any of the above situatios regarding moshe?

Comment: "or for any other reason"

Comment: @Yishai but that does not really seems to be the thrust of the OP, as in his added clarification he writes `Note: A possible answer could include any other source that analyzed the above situations with Moshe and disagreed with Rambam's principle.` Once again implying that only those scenarios with Moshe are the subject of the question.

Comment: @danf in light of the above, perhaps further clarify whether answers not involving Moshe are appropriate.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I don't think DanF gets your ping from here, you would have to write on the question.

Comment: Ray, I have made an edit in my question, per mevaqesh's point. Your answer is interesting, even if it doesn't directly answer my question. I suggest that you leave it, for now, as it provides useful info, nonetheless. If possible, amend it to address anything specific to Moshe's behavior.

Comment: I got a notice that the Community bumped this. In reviewing my comments, I see why I hadn't voted on this at the time. If you have a chance, see if you can locate anything specific to Moses's behavior.